# Android Integration test application permissions

Tags: android, android-testing, android-permissions

I'm looking a way to get current device's serial number in my integration tests.

Now, when calling

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String deviceId = manager.getDeviceId();
```

in my test method, I get `java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10227 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.`

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` in my test project `AndroidManifest.xml`, but that did not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether Read_Phone_State permission is added in your application's AndroidManifest.xml or not.

like This::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

If it is not there please add it, because your testcase can not have more privilege than your application.

Comment: Then it is not possible to access current device's serial number in testcase. Because, your **testcase can not have more privilege than your application**.

Comment: After adding above line, still i am getting an issue how to resolve it

Comment: @karthikpamidimarri have you checked if the permission is present in both the Manifest files (main application as well as test application)

Comment: I also faced same issue with permission. Finally, For development I hard coded the String deviceId. But for Production I used getDeviceId(); It is working in simulator.